# How to get refference to the unmanaged (not COM) interface in C#?

Tags: c#, pointers, interface, unmanaged

I have a native DLL which is implementing some API. The C++ header looks like this:

```
class CAPIInterface
{
public:
    virtual int    __stdcall Release()=0;
    virtual LPCSTR __stdcall ErrorDescription(const int code)=0;
    virtual int  __stdcall Login(const int login,LPCSTR password)=0;
}
```

In C++ a pointer to the interface is acquired this way:

```
typedef int (*APICreate_t)(int version,CAPIInterface **api);

pfnAPICreate =reinterpret_cast<APICreate_t>(::GetProcAddress(hlib,"APICreate"));
CAPIInterface *api=NULL;
if(pfnAPICreate) (*pfnAPICreate)(version,&api);
```

The methods of the interface are called like this:

```
api->Login(123,"password");
```

Now I need to load this native DLL and use the API in my C# program. I managed to load the DLL and acquire the pointer to the native interface this way:

```
    public static class GlobalMembers
    {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public delegate int APICreate_t(time_t version, out IntPtr api);
    }
    ptr_pfnAPICreate = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(hlib,"APICreate");
    pfnAPICreate = (GlobalMembers.APICreate_t)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr_pfnAPICreate, typeof(GlobalMembers.APICreate_t));
    pfnAPICreate(version, out mptr);
```

But now I'm not sure how to map this pointer (mptr) to the C# implementation of the interface. Also I'm not sure how to declare the interface CAPIInterface in C# as well. I tried declaring the interface this way:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class CAPIInterface
{
    public delegate int Release();
    public delegate string ErrorDescription(int code);
    public delegate int Login(int login, string password);
}
```

But then it doesn't compile... it returns this error:
Error   3   Non-invocable member 'CAPIInterface.Login' cannot be used like a method.    I understand that the delegates must be instantiated somewhere as well... but how to do it? Is it correct approach at all to declare the CAPIInterface as above?

Comment: You should try something like http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/CSharp.html that makes it easier

Comment: thanks, but I would prefer calling methods of the native DLL directly from my C# application if possible. Can you give me some recommendations how to do it in my code?

Comment: I have no clue on how to do this, but I was wondering if it would not be easier to make your C++ library COM visible and make C# use the library using COM instead.

Comment: Mapping a C++ class to C# is not for the faint hearted unless you are using a strict COM interface. The simple thing to do would be either to use SWIG or store IntPtrs for your C++ objects and use extern C functions that take your C++ class pointer as the first argument

Comment: I never used SWIG before... can you tell me how to convert my C++ API header with SWIG?

Comment: I did this: unpacked SWIG, created a test project in ...\swigwin-2.0.9\Examples\csharp\ folder, added my API.h to the project, created API.i file and included API.h in it, added API.i file to the project as well. When I try to compile the project it says: Error 2 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __DllMainCRTStartup@12 c:\Programs\swigwin-2.0.9\swigwin-2.0.9\Examples\csharp\API\LINK

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert my C++ API to C# with the help of SWIG. It works great. Thank you.

Comment: can you explain how you did it?